# how to get "View" clicked in ListView not "Complete Row" :: android

Tags: android

We make listener for Items(Rows) click listener in `ListView`. How to get know, in a particular  row a specific View get clicked?

---

### R1 --> TextView1 | TextView2

---

### R2 --> TextView1 | TextView2

I can get which row is clicked. but i also want to know which View of the row get clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set position as tag to textView, and then onClick you can receive its tag.

So basicly you set textView's staff on adapter's getView method

```
textView.setTag(position);
textView.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

And then you'll have click listener like this

```
private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
         int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
         // Do whatever you like...
     }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific click handlers to the textViews:

```
<TextView
    android:onClick="clickHandler">
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void clickHandler(View v) {
    // obtain parent row
    LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();

    // with the parentView you can get all other views as well:
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) parentRow.getChildAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

1. assign onClickListener to whatever can be clicked
2. I assign tag to it to identify v.setTag(R.id.itemId, item.id);
3. In onclick I do:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       final int id = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.itemId);
   }
   ```